# HTML & CSS - Modal is Overlaying another Modal

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

i need to fix this my problem is the first modal you see must be in the back of the white modal how can i change their position?

here is the image

[image]

the black modal should be in the back and the white modal should be in front how can i achieve this? please help thanks.

here is the white modal  I made it jumbotron for purpose

```
    <div class="text-center col-md-8" style="margin-left: 250px;">

         <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1><u>THIS IS AN ANNOUNCEMENT</u></h1>
          <h1>Please read the announcement</h1>
          <h3>You are a safe passenger</h3>
          <h1><?php echo $row['id']; ?> <?php echo $row['additional_info']; ?></h1>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">TAPOS NA!</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

the header shows the white modal

and here is the black modal

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content"> ......
```

style for white modal

```
             <style type="text/css">
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Federo);

    body {
        /* general styles */

        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

    }

    /* overlay styles, all needed */
    .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        z-index: 10;
    }


    .content {
        margin: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I think there should be an overlay class name in white modal in html as you defined properties for class overlay in stylesheet

Comment: check the z-index of your white modal, it should be higher than the black modal.

Comment: howww @BrixAngeles what value should i put?

Comment: what's the z-index of the white modal? Can you post your code?

Comment: @BrixAngeles thankss

Answer (score 0):

I would change the z-index of the white modal.

The z-index assigns a value to the elements which dictates which elements are seen over other elements.

Change your white modal div style to this:

```
<div class="text-center col-md-8" style="margin-left: 250px; z-index:1000;">
```

A z-index of 1000 is pretty high.  You can test by progressively dropping the value down until it hides behind the other modal.  A z-index of 10 may be enough.

You could also examine your current css to see what the highest z-index is and bump it up from that.

Whatever you decide on you can incorporate into a CSS class and just apply the class to the element.

Your CSS shows an overlay class that has a z-index of 10 but I do not see where the overlay class is applied in your code.  Something you might look into.

Hope it helps.